# Get the conditional data in 3rd table by combining data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables :
RoomRateChange , RoomRateCotract and DisplayInventory

RoomRateChange:

```
| RoomID|RateID|Description|RateDate
----------------------
|   101   |  701|   abc       | 2013-04-01 00:00:00.000|
```

RoomRateCotract:

```
| RoomID|RateID|           StartDate    |           EndDate      |Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   101   |  701|2013-04-01 00:00:00.000| 2013-04-30 00:00:00.000|null
```

DisplayInventory:

```
| RoomID|RateID|Description|RateDate
----------------------
```

I am stuck in a situatio. for a particular RoomID,RateID and for a particular Date,
if I have data in RoomRateChange then I should add the description value from RoomRateChange in 3rd table(DisplayInventory) else I should pick the value of description from RoomRateCotract table.

For above scenario ,Output should be

DisplayInventory

```
| RoomID|RateID|Description|RateDate
----------------------
|   101   |  701|  abc     | 2013-04-01 00:00:00.000|
|   101   |  701|  NULL     | 2013-04-02 00:00:00.000|
|   101   |  701|  NULL     | 2013-04-03 00:00:00.000|
```

and so on till 30th.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not 3 rate dates.
Rate dates are all the dates between startdate and enddate.
In DisplayInventory table there will be 30 records.

Comment: There is no Apr 31 in my calendar, how did you set it? o_O

Comment: I am sorry.It's 30th April . :)

Comment: Can you have several Room Rate Changes per RoomID/RateID combination?

Comment: @Bulat : Yes for different dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can use a recursive CTE to get the result:

```
;with data (roomid, rateid, startdate, enddate, description) as
(
  select roomid, rateid, startdate, enddate, description
  from RoomRateCotract
  union all
  select roomid, rateid, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate, description
  from data
  where dateadd(day, 1, startdate) <= enddate
)
-- insert into DisplayInventory
select 
  r.roomid, 
  r.rateid,
  case 
    when r.ratedate = d.startdate 
    then r.description else d.description end description,
  d.startdate RateDate
from data d
left join RoomRateChange r
  on d.roomid = r.roomid
  and d.rateid = r.rateid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0786d/2).

The recursive part will get the list of start/end dates for each room and rate:

```
;with data (roomid, rateid, startdate, enddate, description) as
(
  select roomid, rateid, startdate, enddate, description
  from RoomRateCotract
  union all
  select roomid, rateid, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate, description
  from data
  where dateadd(day, 1, startdate) <= enddate
)
select *
from data
```

Then using the result, you will join to the `RoomRateChange` to get the result.  This could then be used to populate the `DisplayInventory` table.

Comment: Just need to fix  `then r.description else null end description` as there is `description` field in RoomRateCotract.

Comment: @Bulat Unless I am missing something, in the OP they only show the description when the date exists in the `RoomRateChange` if it doesn't then they are showing `null`.

Comment: I read: "else I should pick the value of description from RoomRateCotract table".

Comment: No worries, great answer anyway.